# Django view function not being called on click of submit

Tags: django, forms, django-views, django-urls

I have two view functions in my views.py. The first one renders the index.html 
Second is created for the form action on index.html (update_db). 
 When I click on submit on the index.html file, it changes url to /update1, but the function call has print('HI') and I cannot see that on console. Neither are any new files created after it runs.

> Intially I had return render(request, 'index.html', {} ) but I am not sure if that should be returned. 
>   Is there some problem with my urls.py?

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from .models import Image, Profile
import random
# Create your views here.
def index(request):

    y= random.randint(0,10)
    for i in range(0,10):
        pass 
    p = Image.objects.all()[y]
    print(p.p_img)
    count = p.p_img_count
    lst = [p.s_image1, p.s_image2, p.s_image3, p.s_image3, p.s_image4, p.s_image5]
    tmp =[]
    for i in range(0,3):
        px = Image.objects.all()[random.randint(0,14)]
        tmps=[px.s_image1, px.s_image2, px.s_image3, px.s_image3, px.s_image4, px.s_image5]
        tmp.append(tmps[random.randint(0,4)])

    x = random.randint(0,4)
    s_img = [lst[x]] + tmp
    random.shuffle(s_img)
    print('hevfxy')
    print(p.p_img)

    return render(request,'index.html',{"p_img":p, "s_img": s_img, 'media_url':settings.MEDIA_URL})

def update_db(request):

    print('HI')
    # username = request.user.username
    user = request.POST.get("user")
    p_img = request.POST.get("p_img")
    ans = request.POST.get("ans")

    y = Image.objects.get(p_img=p_img).id
    y=y-8  
    Profile.objects.create(user=user, p_img_id=y, p_ans=ans)

    return something
```

**urls.py** (main conf)

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="login.html"), name="login"),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name="logout.html"), {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
    url('^', include('pair.urls')),


]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path

from . import views
app_name ='pair'

urlpatterns = [
    url('/update1', views.update_db, name='update_db'),
    url('$', views.index, name='index'),

]
```

index.html

```
<form action="/update1" method="POST" >

    {% csrf_token %}

  Player : <b> {{ user.get_username }} </b> 
<p style="background-color: #ddd674">Primary image :
    <input type="hidden" name="user" id="{{ user.get_username }}" value="{{ user.get_username }}"></input>
    <input type="hidden" name="p_img" id="{{ p_img.p_img }}" value="{{ p_img.p_img }}"><img id="p_img" src="{{media_url}}{{ p_img.p_img }}" height=300px ></input>

</p>
<hr height=2px >
<p style="background-color: #a7e0d9">Secondary image :

    {% for img in s_img %}
        {% if img  %}
            <input type="radio" id="{{ img }}" name="ans" value="{{ img }}" >
                <img src="{{media_url}}{{ img }}" height=250px > 
            </input>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <br> 

</p>
<hr>
{{ ans }}

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

Comment: what is the error that you see in the console?

Comment: @Abhyudai There is no error. Just that def index(request) has a print statement in it (and it gets printed on console) and even after clicking on submit.. index view is called ( url in address bar changes to /update1 but 'HI' is not printed)

Comment: That means there's an issue with the urls file. It is directing the request to your index function. Try removing the `$` inside your path for index function.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Even I think the issue is in the urls.py file but I have tried changing the order, the way I am writing the urls, removing and adding slashes but update_db is still not called. Other thing I want to know is if it is okay to `return render(request, "index.html") ` by both index and update_db functions.

Comment: yes you may return the same template for both functions, but logically you might want to use pass different data to the templates (`index.html` in your case), otherwise there's no point using two different functions.

Comment: could you show your `index.html` file?

Comment: Have updated question with the indx.html file.

Comment: your form doesn't seem to have a link to submit(`action` attribute in form). In case you aren't handling that with `javascript`, it will try to make a `POST` request to the same `url`, which is probably the cause in your case.

Comment: I didn't get this. When I click on submit (2nd last line) it should trigger the form action , right?

Comment: Yes, you may read this for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action

Comment: @Abhyudai Hey, all I could find here (and infact in django templates docs as well) is that a form should have an action and it will be triggered when submit is clicked.
 My form has
 `  <form action="/update1" method="POST" > ` 
  and 
   ` <input type="submit"></form> `   .  Shouldn't this be enough?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the `action` attribute while looking at it for the first time. What is the output if you add `print request.method` to your `index` function when submit the form?

Comment: it prints GET ( on calling index function). On clicking submit, update_db should be called. Is there any other method to do the required task in update_db(i.e to create a new profile in db) and return to index.html again?

Comment: what actually does happen when you click on the submit button?

Comment: well for submitting a form you don't really need another function, you might as well check the method in the `index` function, if it's `GET`, server the form, for `POST`, you may process the form.

Comment: ` print(request.method) ` in index function prints GET. After I click submit, url in browser changes to localhost:8000/update1 but in console I can see index being called again.

Comment: does it prints `POST` inside the index function on clicking the submit button?

Comment: Yes. But a GET as well. 
```
p_image/DSC_0268.JPG
hevfxy
**POST**
[26/Dec/2019 17:07:26] "POST /update1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2022
[26/Dec/2019 17:07:26] "GET /media/p_image/DSC_0268.JPG HTTP/1.1" 200 14555287
Not Found: /media/NULL
[26/Dec/2019 17:07:27] "GET /media/NULL HTTP/1.1" 404 1789
[26/Dec/2019 17:07:27] "GET /media/s_image/IMG_1050.JPG HTTP/1.1" 200 7209842
[26/Dec/2019 17:07:27] "GET /media/s_image/DSC_0262.JPG HTTP/1.1" 200 10868701
p_image/children-class-classroom-1720186.jpg
hevfxy
**GET**
[26/Dec/2019 17:07:28] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 2202
```

Comment: this means your form is trying to send a `POST` request to the same url. Just try to use `event.preventdefault()` inside js to prevent this or maybe write the contents of the `db` function inside the `index` function when the request is `POST`

Answer (score 0):

I think your URL is referenced at "localhost:8000//update1" instead of "localhost:8000/update1"

Just change from this:

```
url('/update1', views.update_db, name='update_db')
```

to that:

```
url('update1', views.update_db, name='update_db')
```

Comment: On clicking submit, URL changes to localhost:8000/update1 (with and without the slash) but 'HI' is not printed in console.

Answer (score -1):

You can add any number of methods in your `views.py`. Unless they return a rendered html file, I dont assume django will consider them as views.

My two bets are:

1. Change `url('/update1', views.update_db.as_wiew(), name='update_db'),`
2. Make your update_db method to return something like `return render(something)`.

Hope to hear from you!

Comment: The `print` statement should work in any case but it doesn't. So there seems to be some other issue probably.

Comment: how are you sure that method is being called??

Comment: That is probably the issue here. If it's not being called as per the current state of the original poster, your bets wouldn't be solving them I guess.

Comment: the original poster is trying to reach that method via url and fails. my bets are based on django's inability to recognize that method as a view due to my bets. so "The print statement cannot work in that case" right?

Comment: Actually I want to render index.html only even after clicking the submit button. Update_db is to store the values requested in the function in function. I initally had return render(request, 'index.html') but it would still not print 'HI' indicating it is not being called and that's why I was not sure if rendering index.html is the issue or not.

Comment: @engin_ipek What changes should I make in the url? (.as_view - isn't this used for class views?)