# Django search view not generating html page I set

Tags: python, html, django

I am having trouble getting my search form to work in Django. When I search anything in the search bar I have set, I get an html page that just has the words `Search` on it. It's not the html page I set, though. My search template is in my projects `templates` directory. I am trying to search through my blog posts, and have attached my views and urls code.

This portion of my base template is within a `navbar` I grabbed from a sample Bootstrap blog template. [This is the sample template.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/starter-template/?#) I've changed some things within my form.

`base.html`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css'>
{% load static %}

<!-- Navbar here -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">ChairBlog</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link {% if request.resolver_match.view_name == 'index' %}active{% endif %}" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link {% if request.resolver_match.view_name == 'project_index' %}active{% endif %}" href="{% url 'project_index' %}">Projects </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link {% if request.resolver_match.view_name == 'blog_index' %}active{% endif %}" href="{% url 'blog_index' %}">Blog </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'search' %}" method="GET"> 
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search blog posts...">
          <button class="btn my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- Jumbotron stuff here -->
<div class="jumbotron d-flex align-items-center" style="margin-top: 56px;">
  <div class="container text-center">
    {% block jumbo_content %}

    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Main content goes here -->
<div class="container" style="padding-bottom: 200px;">
    {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
</div>

<!-- Footere here -->
<footer style="position: relative;">
  <div class= "page-footer bg-dark" style="padding-top: 20px; margin-top: 50px;">
      <div class="container" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
        <div class= "row">
          <div class="mb-10 flex-center">
            <a class="github" href="https://github.com/ChairMane"><i class="fa fa-github-square fa-2x"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3" style="color: white;">Chair Birds Co.</div>
  </div>  
</footer>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Nothing within my blocks shows up when I view it. The tags `<p>TEST</p>` and `<p>Is this working?</p>` are not showing up. Neither is the block for the `jumbo_content`. I have set those correctly in my base.html, because they work with my other pages. It's just the search page it doesn't work on.

`search.html`

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block jumbo_content %}
    <h1 class="display-4">Search Results</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<p>TEST</p>
  {% if query %}
      {% if results %}
          <ul>
              {% for post in results %}
                <p>Is this working?</p>
                <li>
                  {{ post.title }}, {{ post.body }}
                </li>
              {% endfor %}
          </ul>
      {% else %}
             <p>Query returned no results.</p>
      {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

`app/views.py`

```py
    ...
def search_posts(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    if query:
        queryset = (Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(body__icontains=query))
        results = Post.objects.filter(queryset).distinct()
    else:
        results = []

    context = {
        'results' : results,
        'query' : query
    }
    return render(request, 'search.html', context)
    ...
```

`app/urls.py`

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.blog_index, name='blog_index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.blog_detail, name='blog_detail'),
    path('<category>/', views.blog_category, name='blog_category'),
    path('search/', views.search_posts, name='search'),
]
```

Here is how the `search` template is being viewed, I believe. My issues are as shown in the image. The inspector shows nothing within the blocks I've set. I have `jumbo_content` and `page_content`, and yet none of what I set within each block shows up. 
[image]

Can anyone see anything immediately wrong here? I've tried [this tutorial](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-search-tutorial) as well, and the same thing happens.

**EDIT** It seems my `search_posts(request)` function in my views is not even being called when I search something in the search bar. I tried tracebacks, and printing and nothing showed up in my terminal. Am I not correctly calling `search_posts(request)`?

Comment: To say exactly what happens you need to share base.html as well. I think you need to add {% block page_content %}{% endblock %} to base.html

Comment: I have now posted my entire `base.html` page. I have those blocks included.

Comment: please show url of your given page also,then I check what a problem in your url?

Comment: The URL I was getting when I searched something was `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/search/?q=Test6`, but now that I got it working, the URL looks like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/search?q=Test6`. So, the `/` was messing me up in my `app/urls.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got my answer. I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480421/django-view-function-not-being-called-on-click-of-submit) and decided to try something. Apparently, if I change my `app/urls.py` line from this:

```py
    path('search/', views.search_posts, name='search'),
```

to this:

```py
    path('search', views.search_posts, name='search'),
```

then my whole view works.

Can anyone explain why that is? I had no idea removing a `/` could help.